# W3schools.com - features don't work in latest Chrome version

Tags: google-chrome, web-sql

I am using w3schools for teaching SQL to my students. We tried the "insert into" command in the SQL editor with some of the examples from the SQL tutorial and get this error message:

> *Error in SQL:
> Operation must use an updateable query.
> Note: Your browser does not support WebSQL, so you are now using a light-version of our Try-SQL Editor, with a read-only Database.
> If you use a browser with WebSQL support (Chrome, Safari, or Opera), you can try any SQL statement, and play with the Database as much as you like.*

It's not a coding mistake because I copied different code snippets directly into the editor. My research suggests that it has to do with the version of the Chrome browser. We are currently using the latest version  119.0.6045.124 (Official Build) (64-Bit). Is there a solution for this problem? We have tried different devices (iPad and Windows PC and Laptop) and it doesn't work anywhere unless the device has the older 118. Version.
I've also tried
**Firefox, Safari, Chrome - I'm hoping I don't have to downgrade because that would not be good. Is there a plug in or some magic that I can use.

All you smart people - PLEASE HELP!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

SQL TryIt Editor isn't working in Google anymore. It looks like Google has removed the ability to use WebSQL in Chrome version 119: [Intent to Deprecate and Remove Web SQL](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/fWYb6evVA-w/m/pziWcvboAgAJ?pli=1).